# Set border link color with hyperref in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref

While the following works in the `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = false, urlbordercolor = {0 1 0}}
\begin{document}
    \href{https://www.google.com/}{Google}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It does not with the `beamer` class:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = false, urlbordercolor = {0 1 0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \href{https://www.google.com/}{Google}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the same result with `beamer` as I do with `article`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border can be enabled by option `pdfborder`. The third number is the border thickness. Since the navigation elements should probably not have borders, the example sets the border in the frame only:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{
  urlbordercolor = {0 1 0},
}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{frame}
  \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}
  \href{https://www.google.com/}{Google}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```